# How to update bootstrap select (selectpicker) header by javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I want to change a select header, I just can't do it.

I tried:

```
$('select').selectpicker({header: "New Header"}).selectpicker('render');
```

and:

```
$('select').selectpicker({header: "New Header"}).selectpicker('refresh');
```

and I updated to latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the header is only set when the selectpicker is initialised. Not on `refresh`, nor on `render`. So I'm afraid the only option left is to set the header by updating the DOM:

```js
$('select').selectpicker({ header: 'Header' });

function changeHeader() {
  $('.popover-title').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  })[0].nodeValue = 'New Header';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="changeHeader()">Change header</button>
```

Comment: Is there any reason to run `$('select').selectpicker({ header: 'Header' });` when we know it doesn't update DOM?

Comment: This line initializes the selectpicker with the `header` option. This one works, the header will be set to "Header". Updating the header however is not possible other than updating the DOM